# box drawing in python

Tags: python, windows, unicode

Platform: WinXP SP2, python 2.5.4.3. (activestate distribution)

Has anyone succeded in writing out [box drawing characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_drawing_characters) in python?
When I try to run this:

```
print u'\u2500'
print u'\u2501'
print u'\u2502'
print u'\u2503'
print u'\u2504'
```

All tips appreciated. What am I doing wrong ? Does python support full unicode ? Is it possible at all to get those characters to print.

#### Related

- [Default encoding for python for stderr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637396/default-encoding-for-python-for-stderr)

Comment: This works for me just fine, do you know if the windows terminal support unicode?

Comment: @cobbal - To be frank, I'm not sure. The last time I used those were in the good ol' dos days. Now I'm experimenting, but a lot changed.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is not in Python but in cmd.exe. It has to be set to support UTF-8. Unfortunately, it is not very easy to switch windows console (cmd.exe) to UTF-8 "Python-compatible" way.

You can use command (in cmd.exe) to switch to UTF8:

```
chcp 65001
```

but Python (2.5) does not recognize that encoding. Anyway you have to set correct font that support unicode!

For box drawing, I recommend to use old dos codepage 437, so you need to set up it before running python script:

```
chcp 437
```

Then you can print cp437 encoded chars directly to stdout or decode chars to unicode and print unicode, try this script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
for i in range(0xB3, 0xDA):
    print chr(i).decode('cp437'),

# without decoding (see comment by J.F.Sebastian)
print ''.join(map(chr, range(0xb3, 0xda)))
```

However, you can use box drawing chars, but you cannot use other chars you may need because of limitation of cp437.

Comment: `print ''.join(map(chr, range(0xb3, 0xda)))` What is the point in decoding to Unicode before printing (when you already done `chcp 437`)?

Comment: You are right, decoding is not nescessary. In general, I prefer to use unicode everywhere and let output functions handle all the encoding.

Answer (score 2):

This varies greatly based on what your terminal supports. If it uses UTF-8, and if Python can detect it, then it works just fine.

```
>>> print u'\u2500'
─
>>> print u'\u2501'
━
>>> print u'\u2502'
│
>>> print u'\u2503'
┃
>>> print u'\u2504'
┄
```

Comment: He's asking about the primitive Windows Console.

Comment: @Gringo: You *do* know that it supports UTF-8 if you run `chcp 65001`... *right*?

Comment: `LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001`

Answer (score 1):

Printing them will print in the default character encoding, which perhaps is not the right encoding for your terminal.

Have you tried transcoding them to utf-8 first?

```
print u'\u2500'.encode('utf-8')
print u'\u2501'.encode('utf-8')
print u'\u2502'.encode('utf-8')
print u'\u2503'.encode('utf-8')
print u'\u2504'.encode('utf-8')
```

This works for me on linux in a terminal that supports utf-8 encoded data.

Answer (score 0):

Python supports Unicode. It is possible to print these characters.

For example, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637396/default-encoding-for-python-for-stderr/638823#638823) to ["Default encoding for python for stderr?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637396/default-encoding-for-python-for-stderr) where I've showed how to print Unicode to `sys.stderr` (replace it by `sys.stdout` for bare `print` statements).

Answer (score 0):

I use the Windows Character Map tool and both in CMD and PowerShell it appears fine. Font: Arial.
Python code:
Exe:
Print('■■■■■■■□□□□□□□')
Print('●●●●●●○○○○○○○○')
And much more!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).